# Navigation/Routing in 3D View On Android

Tags: software-recommendations, routing, android, navigation, 3d-map

I need to build a navigation/routing application in 3D view like sygic, what are the available options if any?

Are there any existing open source or proprietary 3D mapping/libraries?

I have checked MapQuest, CloudMade and Openlayers2, but they don't seem to have this option.

Comment: Some at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android are opensource and 3D and have rendering for Navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar requirements when looking for a Maps API for our [OpenTripPlanner for Android](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/wiki) open-source project, and we decided to go with [Android Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

Android Maps API v2 provides 3D camera control and 3D building renderings out-of-the-box, so you can easily create views like this:

[image]

Android Maps API v2 was feature/performance-wise far beyond the alternativies.  If you prefer OpenStreetMap or other map tiles, you can load these via Android Maps API v2 as well.

The downside is that it requires the user to install [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html?hl=en-US) on their device, but we found this an acceptable tradeoff.

OpenTripPlanner for Android is open-source, and we have 3D real-time navigation in our roadmap, but currently no one is working on this feature.  If you'd like to use OpenTripPlanner for Android as a base for your application please feel free (licensed under Apache v2.0), and we'd definitely welcome any code contributions back to the project.